# Multiple problems with editor and integer field

Tags: gwt

The type com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.NumberLabel is assignable to the raw IsEditor type, but a type parameterization is required

I have  an object with  2 attributes:

id : Integer
categoryName: String

The corresponding fields in the  editor for the above object are :

```
    @UiField
    TextBox id;

    @UiField
    TextBox catNme;
```

When i do a debug  the following message appears :

`[ERROR] Line 17: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to String`

I tried changing the type of id from TextBox to NumberLabel ( in the ui.xml file too) as suggested here:  but now i  get a new error message :

```
[ERROR] [aproj] - The type com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.NumberLabel is assignable to the raw IsEditor type, but a type parameterization is required.
```

What i want to do is make the id editable, if possible without any fuss.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IntegerBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IntegerBox.html) maybe?

If you'd ever want it read-only, use `NumberLabel<Integer>` (in Java, keep `NumberLabel` in UiBinder XML)

Comment: Thanks, was just coming back to post the answer but you were faster.Cheers